# VB.NET Web Service. How I can save in memory the XML request?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, web-services, asmx

I have a web service in VB.NET and I need to control the response time and send an e-mail when the process time is greater than 1 second.

The problem is that when the process time is greater than 1 second, I can not obtain the SOAP request.

I have tried with the SoapExtensions, but in this, I can not obtain the request inside the webmethod. I can only save the response in a file or a database.

How I can obtain the request?

Answer (score 0):

I need obtain the request/response greater than 1 second to check the perfonmance of this.

You can see the code in this link:
[MSDN Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w06t139(v=vs.100).aspx)

The problem is that this example saves the logs in a file, but I need obtain this in memory to determine if I need improve performance and send this for e-mail to check later